# Jython :: does the embedded PythonInterpreter handle Python Source Code Encodings?

Tags: jython

I am using **org.python.util.PythonInterpreter** to embed [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) in a Java application. I am using Jython version **2.5.2**.

he python script I am interpreting contains UTF-8 literals and so I've added the Python Source Code Encoding at the top of the script as per [PEP-0263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

My script is compiled as follows:

```
String script = // load from file as a single String ...
PythonInterpreter pi = new PythonInterpreter();
PyCode code = pi.compile(script);
result = pi.eval(code);
```

However Jython complains with the following trace:

```
 [java]     ... : encoding declaration in Unicode string
 [java]     at org.python.core.ParserFacade.prepBufReader(ParserFacade.java:277)
 [java]     at org.python.core.ParserFacade.parseExpressionOrModule(ParserFacade.java:119)
 [java]     at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.compile(PythonInterpreter.java:259)
 [java]     at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.compile(PythonInterpreter.java:256)
 [java]     at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.compile(PythonInterpreter.java:250)
```

Does Jython support UTF-8 in script files?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an anecdotal answer: as installed by Homebrew on macOS, Jython 2.7.1 **does** support Python Source Code Encoding in the non-embedded command-line interpreter. Hopefully it's also supported beyond that.